# DataTables SearchPanes Cascade not working if button is enabled

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have this issue:

Latest version of DataTables and SearchPanes  downloaded (1.1.1) but when the **SearchPanes *button*** is enabled, then all the related options do not work, especially:

- Cascading
- Layout
- View total

I attached a pic of my folder structure, to show all the modules I have downloaded.

This is my code

```
$('#main-table').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        stateSave:true,
        searchPanes:{
            cascadePanes: true,
            layout: 'columns-4',
            viewTotal: true
        },
        // dom: 'Pfrtip',
        buttons: [ 'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'colvis', 'searchPanes' ],
        fixedHeader: true,
        responsive: true,
        data: table_arr,
        columns: [
        ],
        deferRender: true
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#main-table').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    stateSave:true,
    searchPanes:{
        cascadePanes: true,
        layout: 'columns-4',
        viewTotal: true
    },
    // dom: 'Pfrtip',
    buttons: [
        { 'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'colvis', 'searchPanes' },
        {
            extend: 'searchPanes',
            config: {
                cascadePanes: true
            }],
            fixedHeader: true,
            responsive: true,
            data: table_arr,
            columns: [],
            deferRender: true
        }
    );
```

Comment: Welcome @nilesh on SO. Please explain how your code solves the issue.